# Rally App SDK 2.0: filters and customQuery fail to limit data in rallymultiobjectpicker store in 2.0p3

Tags: javascript, rally

It seems that specifying either or both the 'filters' and 'customQuery' in the storeCfg of a rallymultiobjectpicker in 2.0p3 does not function at all to limit the data in the store. One such scenario would be limiting a rallymultiobjectpicker operating on Tags to display only those that have not been Archived, as shown below:

```
Ext.widget('rallymultiobjectpicker', {
    modelType: 'tag',
    fieldLabel: 'Tags',
    storeCfg: {
        customQuery: '(Archived = false)',
        filters: [
            {
                property: 'Archived',
                value: 'false'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The property you're looking for is called storeConfig rather than storeCfg.  This was an inconsistency in the previous 2.0p2 version of the SDK that we corrected in 2.0p3.  The customQuery property should not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the name change. However, I still have to specify the customQuery. The filter is not working, regardless of whether false is in quotes. This was an issue that existed in 2.0p2, and probably p1, as well.

Comment: You're right- I found the defect for this issue.  I added more info and gave it a bump.

Answer (score 0):

(Based on personal experience and the previous answer)

In the current version of Rally SDK 2, filters do not work correctly in combobox, picker, etc. When the control loads its data on activation, the filter gets ignored.

The workaround is to use customQuery instead of filters. For example:

```
combobox.store.customQuery = this.iterationCombobox.getQueryFromSelected().toString();
combobox.store.load();
```

Changing the customQuery will not reload the store like filters.